# Inline image in xslfo is rendered as block

Tags: image-resizing, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am facing an issue with XSLFO - FOP image rendering, I have several images of different size.
some of the small images are aligned inline with the text and some are big images that occupies a defined space, While displaying big images it would go beyond the viewport and i found a working solution at the [Yahoo groups](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/XSL-FO/message/5861) to restrict it within the viewport, however the given soultion renders both small and big images as block. but i need to render inline image as inline itself and not as block.

I am using following code to render image

```
<fo:external-graphic src="file:{./@src}" width="90%" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform" content-height="100%" vertical-align="middle"/>
```

Image tag doesn't contain any information about inline or block.

Sample:
`<img src="images/real_world_example.jpg" />`

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Text in the above image should align next to the image

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I think that the problem is with your `width="90%"`. Simply delete it, it should work as you expect.